# Unexpected invocation of deleted move constructor by gcc

Tags: c++11, gcc

I'm trying to write a very simple array class with a function that returns a subsection of itself. It is easier to show it than to explain...

```
template<typename T>
class myArrayType
{
   // Constructor; the buffer pointed to by 'data' must be held 
   // elsewhere and remain valid for the lifetime of the object
   myArrayType(int size, T* data) : n(size), p(data)
   {
   }

   // A move constructor and assign operator wouldn't make 
   //much sense for this type of object:
#ifndef _MSC_VER
    myArrayType(myArrayType<T> &&source) = delete;
    myArrayType & operator=(myArrayType<T> &&source) && = delete;
#else
  #if _MSC_VER >= 2000
      myArrayType(myArrayType<T> &&source) = delete;
      myArrayType & operator=(myArrayType<T> &&source) && = delete;
  #endif
  // Earlier versions of Visual C++ do not generate default move members
#endif

   // Various whole-array operations, which is the main reason for wanting to do this:
   myArrayType & operator+=(const myArrayType &anotherArray) & noexcept
   {
       for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) p[i] += anotherArray.p[i];
       return *this;
   }

   // etc.


   // The interesting bit: create a new myArrayType object which is 
   // a subsection of this one and shares the same memory buffer
   myArrayType operator()(int firstelement, int lastelement) noexcept
   {
       myArrayType newObject;
       newObject.p = &p[firstelement];
       newObject.n = lastelement - firstelement + 1;
       return newObject;
   }


private:
    T*  p;
    int n;
}
```

What I'd like to do, of course, is to be able to write:

```
double aBigBlobOfMemory[1000];  // Keep it on the stack
myArrayType<double> myArray(1000, aBigBlobOfMemory);

myArrayType<double> mySmallerArray = myArray(250, 750);
```

...so that 'mySmallerArray' is a fully-formed myArrayType object which contains a pointer to a subset of myArray's memory.

In Visual Studio 2013 this seems to work (or at least, it compiles), but in gcc it fails in a way that I don't understand. The compiler error on the attempted creation of mySmallerArray is:

```
use of deleted function myArrayType(myArrayType<T> &&)
```

...with a caret pointing to the end of the line. In other words, gcc seems to think that in invoking the 'subarray operator' I'm actually trying to invoke a move constructor, but I can't for the life of me see where it would want to use one, or why.

Am I missing something really really obvious, or can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? On what line?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg On the line "myArrayType<double> mySmallerArray = myArray(250, 750);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc is doing the right thing.

From operator() you are returning newObject, an instance of myArrayType.  This has to be *moved* into the variable mySmallerArray.  That's done with a move constructor, which you don't have.

You need to declare a move constructor.

It does make sense for this class to have a move constructor - it can move the pointer p from the existing instance to the new one.

Comment: Fair enough; I guess that the reason I don't get any error in Visual Studio is that it doesn't occur to the compiler to attempt a move here so it does a copy by default.

Comment: Visual C++ is optimizing things so that newArray and mySmallerArray refer to the same location on the stack, so it doesn't have to invoke the move constructor.  That optimization is specifically allowed by the standard (but not required).

Comment: Aha, Return Value Optimisation; to be honest, in the first instance I was expecting both compilers to do precisely that, so I couldn't understand why gcc was doing something different. If a compiler wasn't doing RVO, I thought perhaps it would do a copy; doing a move never occurred to me.